# running an openGL engine in WPF in a separate thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, opengl

I have an openGL rendering engine coded in unmanaged C++, and I want to embed this in a WPF application. After a little research, I managed to do it by using the handle of a windows forms panel in a windowsformshost, as explained here (**2nd solution**):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127141/Unmanaged-C-OpenGL-Drawing-and-C-WinForms-WPF-inte/?display=Mobile

So far good. The problem is, I need the render to be real time, and when some UI operation takes too long (like populating a property grid), the render flickers.

Then I guess I need to do the rendering in a separate thread. I tried to use this approach:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx

But it does not work because it seems i cannot place a windowsformshost inside a HostVisual (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/124cc95c-a9c6-4aca-a5fc-4f959ea715c3)

So, any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use double-buffering then it should never flicker. See the section "How to Avoid Flickering?" in the first article you linked to. You can also try inserting Application.DoEvents() calls inside code that takes a long time to execute. Just some suggestions as an alternative to the added complexity of using a threaded solution.

EDIT: just realized WPF does not support DoEvents(), but there are alternatives: http://nmarian.blogspot.com/2007/09/doevents-in-wpf.html

Comment: I already implemented the "how to avoid flickering" section of the article, and it does not flicker on normal operation, resizing, etc.. It flickers when I populate a 3rd party property grid because it composes itself in the UI thread and it takes some time, and I am using the same Dispatcher to render the opengl. That wpf DoEvents workaround is interesting but I cannot insert it anywhere as it is 3rd party code. Anyway thanks for the reply